# Quantum state with zero standard deviation of position operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Is any quantum state $|\psi\rangle$  possible such that the standard deviation $\sqrt{\langle\psi|(\Delta\hat{x})^2|\psi\rangle}$ of the position operator $\hat{x}$ is zero? If not, why?

Comment: What does the uncertainty principle tell you about the spread in momentum for such a state? (Hint: The delta function $\delta(x)$ is the Fourier transform of the constant function.)

Comment: But, Uncertainity principle holds only when momentum and position are measured simultaneously. The question would not measure momentum - thus would not have to obey the uncertainity principle, right ?

Comment: The uncertainty principle is not a statement about measurements but a property of the state itself. Basically, your state is a superposition of waves of all momenta, with equal amplitudes. Besides the fact that at some point the highest momentum modes will put you beyond currently known physics, such a state will quickly smear out as the fastest waves simply "run away". So it is just a delta function for an instant in time, and then no more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative. If there were such a state, $\psi$, it would satisfy 
$$\langle \psi| X^2 \psi \rangle - \langle \psi| X \psi \rangle^2= 0 \quad (1)$$ 
namely
$$\langle \psi| X^2 \psi \rangle = \langle \psi| X \psi \rangle^2$$ 
that is, since $X=X^\dagger$ and $||\psi||=1$:
$$\langle \psi| X \psi \rangle^2 = \langle X\psi| X \psi \rangle \langle \psi |\psi \rangle\:.\quad (2)$$
On the other hand,  Cauchy-Schwarz' inequality implies 
$$\langle \psi| X \psi \rangle^2 \leq  \langle X\psi| X \psi \rangle \langle \psi |\psi \rangle\:,$$
where, as is known $=$ holds if and only if the two vectors in the LHS scalar product are proportional. Since it is the case due to (2), we conclude that:
$$X\psi = \lambda \psi$$
for some $\lambda \in \mathbb C$. However, as is known,the operator  $X$ has no eigenvectors, its spectrum being purely continuous: $\sigma(X)= \mathbb R$. Therefore $\psi$ does **not** exist.

Nevertheless, *formally speaking*, you could think of distributions $\psi_{x_0}(x) =\delta(x-x_0)$ as formal eigenvectors of $X$, with eigenvalue $x_0$.  These formal states, indicated by $|x_0\rangle$ with the suggestive (and very useful) Dirac notation, do not belong to the Hilbert space of the theory $L^2(\mathbb R)$, since they are not (equivalence classes of) functions.

It is possible to extend the formalism (as done by Gelfand) to include these distributions as defining generalized states into a rigorous mathematical sense. In that case, however,  (1) cannot be intepretated literally for these generalized states, since it would involve  products of $\delta$ functions which cannot be defined.

Comment: Then this would mean that,

$[\int_{- \propto }^{ \propto } f (x)x dx]^{2} = \int_{- \propto }^{ \propto } f(x) x^{2} dx $


If, $\int_{- \propto }^{ \propto }  f(x)^{2} dx$ = exists 

Thus, would only a trivial solution to the above equation exist ? Apologies - I am severly handicapped with TeX. The alphas are infinity limits.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What is your $f$ respect to my $\psi$?

Comment: $f$ functions the same way as $\psi$ does. I believe then you would point at $\psi$ being a complex function ?

Comment: I now understand. YES, provided in the first couple of integrals you wrote, $|f(x)|^2$ appears in place of $f(x)$.

Comment: I mean: The probability density is $|\psi(x)|^2$. OK?

Comment: Yes, we're on the same page on that. Thank you very much, it's been of great help !

Comment: Would $|x\rangle$, eigenstate of position, satisfy Eq. (1)?

Comment: No: $\langle x|X^2 |x\rangle = x^2 \langle x|x\rangle$ and $\langle x|x\rangle$ does not make sense. Obviously the same happens for $X$.

Comment: Nevertheless back to the op's question, if the state is at the eigenstate of position, physically do we expect the standard deviation is zero? Each time we measure the position, we just obtain the same position eigenvalue.

Comment: There are no eigenstates of the position operator in QM since $X$ has continuous spectrum. Things like $|x_0\rangle$ do not correspond to any real physical state, even if you can construct normalixed states $\psi_\epsilon$ arbitrarily close to such object: $|x_0\rangle$: $||X\psi_\epsilon - x_0\psi_\epsilon||^2 < \epsilon$ with $||\psi_\epsilon||=1$.

Comment: If there is no eigenstate of position operator, what does coordinate representation mean? E.g. $\langle x | p |\psi \rangle = - i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} $, the bra vector $\langle x |$ corresponds to an eigenstate of position operator.

Comment: The position rep. is the representation where (1) the Hilbert space is $L^2(\sigma(X))$ and (2) the position operator $X$ is multiplicative. $\sigma(X)$, the spectrum of $X$, is the set of the values of the position observable. These values do not correspond to eigenvalues as in the case of point spectrum. In the space of states, there are no things as eigenvectors of observables with continuous spectrum. The proof I wrote is general: An eigenstate has zero standard deviation referring to its observable.

Comment: Things like $|x\rangle$ are formal objects very useful in computations, but they are not vectors in the Hilbert space of the theory. It is however possible to enlarge the theory in order to include similar objects in some way. In that case the space of states ceases to be a Hilbert space and becomes a so called rigged Hilbert space, which is a much more complicated structure where part of the standard QM interpretation fails however (e.g $\langle x|x\rangle$ does not make sense instead of being $1$).